# Toast cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, toast

I am trying to show a toast when click on a button that button request's a listener. I am logging out through this button and i want to show toast on loggout completion so i put toast in onComplete method of request Listener. Here is my complete code

**HomeActivity which contains button listeners**

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private static final String TAG = "Facebook";
private Button mLogin, mLogout, mShare;
private Facebook facebook;
private AsyncFacebookRunner abRunner;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    //mLogin.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    // Initialize facebook objects
    facebook = new Facebook("479652662068145");
    abRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

    // Setup VIews
    mLogin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);
    mLogout= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Logout);

    mLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    mLogout.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v){

   int id = v.getId();
   switch(id){
   case R.id.Login:
       FacebookLoginDialog login = new FacebookLoginDialog();
       facebook.authorize(this, login);
        break;
   case R.id.Logout:
       FacebookLogoutRequest logout = new FacebookLogoutRequest(this);
       abRunner.logout(this, logout);
       break;
        default:
            break;

   }
 }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);
    return true;
 }



 }
```

**And my RequestListener Code**

```
public class FacebookLogoutRequest implements RequestListener{

private Context context;

public FacebookLogoutRequest (Context context){

this.context= context;
 }
public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "You Are Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
}

@Override
public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


 }
```

Please Help I am stuck here..Thanks

Comment: App runs fine but when I click on Logout But and my app says forceclose

Comment: you might need to import a toaster :) In all seriousness though, are you sure that passing in `this` is sufficient for a `Context`? I remember something about a `getApplicationContext` method... maybe that would help?

Comment: App runs fine but when I click on Logout button logout is done successful But my app says forceclose

Comment: So post logcat error stacktrace.

Comment: getApplicationContext is not working. Or may be I am not using it correctly can you tell how can I use it in above code.

Comment: Whats the stacktrace then? You should probably post the LogCat output for us to see. Just in case you are unaware of how to use logcat http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: try replacing abRunner.logout(this, logout); with abRunner.logout(HomeActivity.this, logout);

Comment: code looks good. you have to provide the stacktrace of the crash

Comment: Hi everyone how can i provide stacktrace? Logcat is very large that i cant paste here.

Comment: Hi everyone you require complete logcat or just error related?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Activity instead of Context because context is not for UI reference

```
public class FacebookLogoutRequest implements RequestListener{

    private Activity context;

    public FacebookLogoutRequest (Activity context){

    this.context= context;
     }
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "You Are Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Comment: THanks but no result.. same exception

Comment: can u send me a logcat @ rishabh@creatiosoft.com

Comment: Hi Rishabh I have sent you logcat plz check it

Comment: AsyncFacebookRunner is a using AsyncTask as a inner class.AsyncTask does not a UI Thread.So It can not show Toast.You should implement call back function which you notify that user successfully logout with his account then show toast in your activity

Comment: One more question I am starting new activity in dialoglistener's on Complete method. Declaring above context but activity doesn't start